# Getting "bson_decimal128_from_string" error trying to build mongo-php-driver

Tags: php, mongodb, centos

```
CentOS release 6.7 (centos-release-6-7.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64)
kernel 2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64
```

We had successfully built the mongo-php-driver with the instructions [found here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php)

Last week I spun up a new instance, patched it via yum update, and tried to build - and I'm consistently getting this error now:

```
>> make install
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib64/php/modules/
>> service php-fpm restart
Stopping php-fpm:                                          [  OK  ]
Starting php-fpm: [12-Apr-2016 14:38:39] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongodb.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: bson_decimal128_from_string in Unknown on line 0
```

The build returns no errors, and seems to build the bson libraries as it goes:

```
checking for uint64_t... yes
... seen our uintptr_t in stdint.h (uint64_t too)
creating ./src/libbson/src/bson/bson-stdint.h : ___SRC_LIBBSON_SRC_BSON_BSON_STDINT_H
checking for int_least32_t... yes
checking for int_fast32_t... yes
..adding include stdint.h
... seen good stdint.h inttypes
... seen good uint64_t
... DONE ./src/libbson/src/bson/bson-stdint.h

* snip *

Build configuration:
  CFLAGS                                           : -g -O2
  Extra CFLAGS                                     :  -pthread
  Developers flags (slow)                          :
  Code Coverage flags (extra slow)                 :
  System mongoc                                    : no
  System libbson                                   : no
  LDFLAGS                                          :
  EXTRA_LDFLAGS                                    :
  MONGODB_SHARED_LIBADD                            : -lsasl2  -lssl -lcrypto -lrt
```

So far I have tried (and failed):

1. Deleting the mongodb.so file, repulling from github, and rebuilding
2. Descending into the src/libbson directory, building there, then
   ascending and building again
3. Removing any packages containing bson (which include libbson and libbson-devel) using yum, in case it was building agains the wrong lib

My google-fu has failed me, and I can't find anything on SO about it. Anyone hit this kind of issue, or know a fix?